# write or stop statements break f2py compilation

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

I am trying to compile a little `fortran` module to be used with `python` using `f2py`. It compiles and works if I remove the `write(*,*) ...` and `stop ...` statements, but when I include either of those, compilations exits with an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /share/apps/gcc/4.7.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.1/../../../../lib64/libgfortran.a(stop.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/share/apps/gcc/4.7.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.1/../../../../lib64/libgfortran.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/ld: /share/apps/gcc/4.7.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.1/../../../../lib64/libgfortran.a(stop.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/share/apps/gcc/4.7.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.1/../../../../lib64/libgfortran.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`gcc` is version 4.7.1, `numpy` is 1.8.0, I compiled it with a simple

```
f2py -c -m integration integration_module.f90
```

Any ideas or workarounds?

**Edit:**

The files and output can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e23415927d23207044a0).

Comment: show the actual code. stop followed by parenthesis is not valid syntax

Comment: The brackets were just a typo. The problem is also not really the code, but probably the compiler/library combination, I think. On my Mac, these modules and others compile and work just fine, the problem is only on a another computer (not managed by myself). I added the link to the full output and code in the question.